# Funciones JavaScript equivalentes en PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo este código en JavaScript, obteniendo los valores de unos datepicker y funciona de manera correcta:

```
var fecha_ini = $('.fecha_ini').val();
var fecha_ini_dia = fecha_ini.substring(0,2);
var fecha_ini_mes = fecha_ini.substring(3,5);
var fecha_ini_anio = fecha_ini.substring(6,10);

var fecha_fin = $('.fecha_fin').val();
var fecha_fin_dia = fecha_fin.substring(0,2);
var fecha_fin_mes = fecha_fin.substring(3,5);
var fecha_fin_anio = fecha_fin.substring(6,10);

var fecha_ini_horas = new Date(fecha_ini_anio,parseInt(fecha_ini_mes)-1,fecha_ini_dia,0,0,0);
var fecha_fin_horas = new Date(fecha_fin_anio,parseInt(fecha_fin_mes)-1,fecha_fin_dia,0,0,0);
```

Solo que estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo con código en PHP pero no sale. ¿Cuál sería el bloque de código equivalente en dicho lenguaje?

Comment: Por qué no usar `<php? <script> tu código </script></php>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que ya tengas definida tu fecha en una variable o la traigas de una solicitud a tu archivo de `php` por un formulario o por la url, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$fecha_ini = $_GET['fecha_ini'];
$fecha_ini_dia = substr($fecha_ini,0,2);
$fecha_ini_mes = substr($fecha_ini,3,5);
$fecha_ini_anio = substr($fecha_ini,6,10);

$fecha_fin = $_GET['fecha_fin'];
$fecha_fin_dia = substr($fecha_fin,0,2);
$fecha_fin_mes = substr($fecha_fin,3,5);
$fecha_fin_anio = substr($fecha_fin,6,10);

$delimitador = '-';

$fecha_ini_horas = new DateTime($fecha_ini_anio.$delimitador.$fecha_ini_mes.$delimitador.$fecha_ini_dia);
$fecha_fin_horas = new DateTime($fecha_fin_anio.$delimitador.$fecha_fin_mes.$delimitador.$fecha_fin_dia);
```

Si tu fecha tiene el formato `dia-mes-año` o `año-mes-dia`
puedes pasarle directamente tu fecha, sin tener que dividirla en las partes 
correspondientes a los días, mes y año.

```
$fecha_ini = $_GET['fecha_ini'];
$fecha_fin = $_GET['fecha_fin'];
$fecha_ini_horas = new DateTime(fecha_ini);
$fecha_fin_horas = new DateTime(fecha_fin);
```

Sino si empleas otro delimitador o el orden no es el de dia, mes , año entonces puedes usar la función estática **createFromFormat** de la clase DateTime para indicar que formato tiene la cadena que quieres convertir.
Si por ejemplo fuera mes/dia/año (12/28/2017)

```
$fecha_ini = $_GET['fecha_ini'];
$fecha_fin = $_GET['fecha_fin'];
$fecha_ini_horas = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', fecha_ini);
$fecha_fin_horas = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', fecha_fin);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero sale un error DateTime::__construct() expects at most 2 parameters, 6 given

Comment: revisa la edité.

Comment: No bro :( ya vi esa función y debe recibir como máximo 2 parámetros

Comment: Si revisas bien yo pase solo 1 parametro lo que esta concatenado con 4 variables